# local sync of calendar and contacts between android and mac?

Tags: android

What is the preferred approach to locally sync (i.e., assume I have no Google account of any kind) the following data between an Android phone and my Macbook?

- calendar
- tasks
- address book / contacts

I have done some digging online but apparently this is not a common use case. I found some information here, but it looks out of date: http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/android_sync/

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: i'm on a rather old version but i plan to upgrade to Sierra soon (I guess?) -- now that Firefox is sunsetting support for older OS versions, i haven't much choice.